# Unable to connect mongodb with remote public IP server

Tags: java, mongodb

I am facing a problem connecting to mongodb from my machine to public IP server on which mongodb installed as a windows service with --auth

When I removed authentication as below command, I am able to access the database collection

```
mongod --install --noauth --dbpath  "c:\mongodb\data" --logpath
"c:\mongodb\logs\log.txt" --bind_ip "0.0.0.0"
```

And when I use the `--auth` in place of `--noauth`, I am getting the following error:

> errmsg : "auth failed" code :18 login failed

And I am giving correct login details to connect to the mongodb.

What is causing this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Make sure you don't forget to state your question, and format your code!

Answer (score 0):

What command are you using to connect to your database?
If you use mongo like `mongo -u login -p password -h xxx.yyy.zzz.aaa` try to add `--authenticationDatabase admin`.

Comment: DB db = null;
  try {
   List<MongoCredential> credentials = new ArrayList<MongoCredential>();
   credentials.add(
        MongoCredential.createMongoCRCredential(
            "user",
            "DBname",
            "pwd".toCharArray()
        )
    );
  db = DBContext.getInstance(new ServerAddress("address")).getDB("DBname");   Here is the code i am using

Comment: Event i tried the same and am getting the same error.

Comment: Are you able to authenticate using the mongo shell ?

`mongo -u login -p password -h xxx.yyy.zzz.aaa --authenticationDatabase admin`